# Unable to maintain strokeWidth for fabricjs group element

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Hi I am working on fabricjs library and stuck with a bug.

I am drawing a group of Text and Rect and then re-sizing it. 
But I see that the size of group @borders increase with re-sizing .
But I want the strokeWidth to be same through out .

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/6CDFr/263/)!.

Code : 
`

```
var gCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvDraw');
 gCanvas.setWidth(500);
 gCanvas.setHeight(500);

var myEllipse = new fabric.Ellipse({
top: 250,
left: 100,
rx: 75,
ry: 50,
fill: '#999999',
stroke: '#000000',
strokeWidth: 2
});

var myText = new fabric.Text("Some text", {
top: 250,
left: 250,
});


// set up a listener for the event where the object has been modified
gCanvas.observe('object:modified', function (e) {
var objects = gCanvas.getObjects();
for (i in objects) {
    console.log(objects[i]);
    objects[i].strokeWidth = 2;
}
}); 
var group = new fabric.Group([ myEllipse, myText ], {borderColor: 'black', cornerColor: 'green'});
gCanvas.add(group);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se updated fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/6CDFr/264/
for dynamic strokewidth change.

```
gCanvas.observe('object:modified', function (e) {
var myObject = e.target;

if (!myObject._objects) {
  return;
}
for (i in myObject._objects) {
    objects[i].strokeWidth = 2 / Math.sqrt(myObject.scaleX * myObject.scaleY);
}
});
```

Be carefull i removed a couple of `canvas.add();` You should not add objects both to canvas and to group.

Mantain also TEXT dimensions:

```
gCanvas.observe('object:added', function (e) {
    if (e.target.type === 'text' || e.target.type === 'i-text') {
        e.target.originalFontsize = e.target.fontSize;
    }
});
gCanvas.observe('object:modified', function (e) {
var myObject = e.target;

if (!myObject._objects) {
  return;
}
for (i in myObject._objects) {
    var obj = myObject._objects[i];
    var scaleFactor = Math.sqrt(myObject.scaleX * myObject.scaleY);
    obj.strokeWidth = 2 / scaleFactor;
    if (obj.type === 'text' || obj.type === 'i-text') {
        obj.fontSize = obj.originalFontsize / scaleFactor;
    }
}
});
```

see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6CDFr/269/

Comment: Thanks for the answer .But one question , can we not maintain the size of text similarly. I don't want the size of text to increase/decrease on resizing

Comment: i add also this to the answer, but there is a similar question i did a week ago, please search better .

Comment: please accept the answer if it solve, so other users can find them. Change te tile to reflect also mantaining fontSize and group borders while scaling.

Comment: sorry for the late reply , it was late night when you answered . Now I am using your code , but if I resize now , the text just disappears , please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: I have update fiddle with your answer . Please have a look . In order not to disturb your code I maintained a separate loop . http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/6CDFr/267/

Comment: i updated your fiddle, you forgot the object:added part.  PLease do not make fiddles on fabric version 0.9 is very old.

Comment: it is still the same , Are you referring to http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/6CDFr/267/  . Sorry , too many fiddles ,so a bit confused

Comment: Okay got it. Its  http://jsfiddle.net/6CDFr/269/ . Thanks bro , now that works perfectly